# Convert 0x001234AB to NSString "001234AB"

Tags: objective-c

I used Google, and Bing and SO, and I get literally hundreds of answers how to convert string to an integer, but cannot find a single example how to convert a number to a string in HEX base. And I need to convert thousands (into the same string) so a faster method is preferred.

```
int x = 0x001234ab;
NSString str;
<-------  what should behere?
NSLog(str); // outputs "001234AB" or "001234ab"
```

Comment: Hint: `NSString` has a `stringWithFormat:` method ...

Answer (score 2):

```
NSLog(@"%x", x);
```

Or if you want it in string.

```
NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%x", x];
```

If you want leading zeros your format will look like this

```
@"%0yx"
```

where y is number of zeros (for your example 8).

Comment: how about leading zeroes?

Comment: that's not possible, because at runtime it is unknown how the integer was stored. is you data source a source code file?

Comment: @exebook you can set minimum number of characters it will print. For your example you need `%08x` but you can't detect it in code as @JeanLuc stated.

Comment: And lowercase/uppercase x/X if you want hex numbers in lower/uppercase.